# C# JSON-RPC webserver without ASP.NET

Tags: c#, console, json-rpc

I am amazed that I have not found a single simple C# console app that will be able to handle a couple of JSON-RPC commands as a server. Is there anyway to implement this with potentially unlimited calls and a lightweight/easy way, I could compare the calling string manually and decide which function to call for all I care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick start for [json-rpc.net](http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com) running in a console.
http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20%28Console%29&referringTitle=Documentation